# Directive v-focus on one input why rest of the input field is not able to type properly in vue js

Tags: vue.js, vue-material

When i try to focus on a single input field on a button click, that input field will be always focused 
i cannot enter data into the second input field if i try to insert a word on keyup it will be focused to the first field

```
<div id="app">
   <md-field>
      <label>Value 1</label>
      <md-input v-model="initial" v-focus :disabled="valDisabled"></md-input>
    </md-field>
    <md-field>
      <label>Value 2</label>
      <md-input v-model="type" :disabled="valDisabled"></md-input>
    </md-field>

    <md-button class="md-raised md-primary" id="btnAddMore" v-on:click="SubmitButton">Submit</md-button>
  </div>
<script>

Vue.directive('focus', {
    inserted: function (el) {
        el.focus();
    },
    update: function (el) {
        Vue.nextTick(function() {
            el.focus();
        })
    }
})
var app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: function () {
        return {
          initial: "",
          type: "",
          valDisabled: true
        };
    },
method:funtion(){
SubmitButton:funtion(){
    this.valDisabled = false;
}
},
</script>
```

please help

Comment: Well it focusses on the first input constantly because of the `focus()` function in your `update` method in your directive. What's the function of the directive in the first place? What do you want to achieve with it?

Comment: When i click Submit Button i need to make the first field as focus and need to start enter value to avoid the use of mouse to select that field

Comment: Any updates. Please some one help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If nothing works, go the old fashioned js way using "id" on the input element and then on SubmitButton click give the element focus.

1) html: `<md-input v-model="initial"  id="someid" :disabled="valDisabled" ></md-input>`

2)

```
SubmitButton () {
  this.valDisabled = false;

  // nextTick is used to bring valDisabled change into effect.
  // Otherwise, it won't get focus.
  this.$nextTick(() => {
    document.getElementById("someid").focus();
  });
}
```

No need for v-focus directive in this case.